# How does a Rails fixture find its model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2, fixtures

I've created a model that changes its table name, and now the fixture doesn't seem to be able to find it. Is there something I need to do to tell the fixture which model to use?

I'm using Rails 2.0.5.

The symptom is that when I run `rake db:fixtures:load`, I get an error that the `id` field cannot be null.

It's weird, because I have another model that is changing its table name, and it works fine.

I have two tables: `customer` and `long_prefix_orders`. They both have required `id` fields.

I have two models that look something like this:

```
# app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :customer
end

# app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :long_prefix_orders
end
```

I have two fixtures that look something like this:

```
# test/fixtures/customer.yml
one:
  name: Bob

# test/fixtures/long_prefix_orders.yml
one:
  name: Party Supplies
  customer_id: one
```

The customer fixture works, and the order fixture doesn't. Is changing the table name from plural to singular a small enough change that the fixture can find it, or is there some other configuration that I've forgotten about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here was that I was using `customer_id` instead of `customer` when I referred to the parent record. Use the name of the relationship in fixtures, not the name of the database field.